# python-tkinter problema con command en button

Tags: python, tkinter

Tengo el siguiente codigo con una clase formulario que llama al modulo `componentes.py` que contiene unas funciones basicas para generar formularios basicos.

En principio solo se cree el ingreso de usuario y contraseña, hasta ahi va bien, pero luego he creado otro madulo llamado verificar en donde estoy tratando chequear de algun modo ususario y contraseña, pero el problema es que cuando mediante el `command` del button llamo a la func chequear del modulo verificar este no espera a que yo presione dicho boton "entrar" par realizar dicha función sino que se ejecuta automáticamente y como no coloqué nada dispara directamente el mensaje de error. Luego me permite poner usuario y clave pero al presionar "entrar" dice que falta un argumento (`TypeError: chequear() missing 1 required positional argument: 'lista'`).

Les agradecere su ayuda porque quiero resolver esete simple ejercicio que me propuse y me esta costando.

```
import tkinter as tk
import componentes as cpt
import verificar as vf

""" FORMULARIO DE INGRESO permite accder a la app en si """

class Formularios():

    def __init__(self):

        self.listaCaja=[]
        self.listaBoton=[]
        self.listaEtiqueta=[]
        self.comando=[]

    #----------- VENTANA ACCESO -----------

    def acceso(self):

        lista=("USUARIO:", "CLAVE:")
        lista2=("ENTRAR", "SALIR")

        raiz=tk.Tk()
        raiz.resizable(0, 0)
        raiz.title("Ingreso de Usuarios")

        marcoUno=tk.Frame(raiz, width="200", height="100")
        marcoUno.grid(column=0, row=0) 

        marcoDos=tk.Frame(raiz, width="200", height="50")
        marcoDos.grid(column= 0, row=1)

        #----------- ETIQUETAS mUNO-----------

        for i in range(len(lista)):
            self.listaEtiqueta.append(cpt.crear_E(marcoUno, lista[i]))
            cpt.ordenar(self.listaEtiqueta[i], i, 0, 5)

        #----------- CAJAS TEXTO mUNO-----------

        for i in range(len(lista)):
            self.listaCaja.append(cpt.crear_C(marcoUno, "20"))
            cpt.ordenar(self.listaCaja[i], i, 1, 5, 5)


        #----------- BOTONES mDOS-----------

        vf.chequear(self.listaCaja)
        self.comando=[vf.chequear, quit]



        for i in range(len(lista2)):
            self.listaBoton.append(cpt.crear_B(marcoDos, lista2[i], "10", self.comando[i]))
            cpt.ordenar(self.listaBoton[i], 0, i, 5, 2, "", 1)


        raiz.mainloop()


raiz=Formularios()      
raiz.acceso()
```

```
#                       ----componentes.py-----

import tkinter as tk

"""Este módulo está orientado a crear componentes sencillos de un formulario"""

#---------- ORDENAR ELEMENTOS ------------------

def ordenar(obj="", fila=0, col=0, x=0, y=0, coord="", cols=1, rows=1):
    obj.grid(row=fila, column=col,  padx=x, pady=y, sticky=coord, columnspan=cols, rowspan=rows)


#---------- CREAR ELEMENTOS ------------------

def crear_E(contenedor, titulo=""):
    etiqueta=tk.Label(contenedor, text= titulo)
    return etiqueta 


def crear_C(contenedor, ancho="15"):
    caja=tk.Entry(contenedor, width= ancho)
    return caja


def crear_B(contenedor, titulo="", ancho="10", comando=""):
    boton=tk.Button(contenedor, text=titulo, width=ancho, command=comando)
    return boton
```

```
#                    ----verifica.py-----

from tkinter import messagebox

def chequear(lista):
    if lista[0].get() == 1 and lista[1].get() == 2:
        print("ok") 
    else:
        messagebox.showwarning(title= "Denegado", message= "Su autenticación es Incorrecta")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu función verificar se ejecuta ¡porque la estás llamando!

Mira, en esta línea dentro del método `Formularios.acceso`:

```
    #----------- BOTONES mDOS-----------

    vf.chequear(self.listaCaja)   # <---------   AQUI!
    self.comando=[vf.chequear, quit]
```

Debes eliminar esa llamada, y dejar que sea Tkinter quien invoque esa función cuando el usuario pulse el botón apropiado.

Pero entonces tendrás otro problema, y es que el método que asignas a ese botón mediante estas líneas:

```
    self.comando=[vf.chequear, quit]
    for i in range(len(lista2)):
        self.listaBoton.append(cpt.crear_B(marcoDos, lista2[i], "10", self.comando[i]))
        cpt.ordenar(self.listaBoton[i], 0, i, 5, 2, "", 1)
```

Será el método `vf.chequear`. Si observamos el código de ese método (en el fichero `verificar.py`) se observan dos problemas:

```
def chequear(lista):
    if lista[0].get() == 1 and lista[1].get() == 2:
        print("ok") 
    else:
        messagebox.showwarning(title= "Denegado", message= "Su autenticación es Incorrecta")
```

El primero es que estás comparando el contenido de las cajas de texto con los números `1` y `2`. Esto siempre va a ser falso, ya que lo que contienen esas cajas son cadenas y no números. Debes usar en su lugar `"1"` y `"2"`.

Pero el problema más grave es que esta función espera un parámetro (`lista`), pero no hay forma de pasar parámetros a los comandos de los botones, ya que quien invoca esos comandos es Tkinter como vimos antes ¿cómo va a saber Tkinter qué parámetros pasarle?

La práctica habitual es usar como `command` un método de la clase en la que está el botón, para que de ese modo ese método tenga acceso a los atributos de la clase, tales como `self.listaCaja` y pueda extraer de ahi lo que necesite.

Por tanto puedes cambiar la asignación de comandos a botones para que use:

```
    self.comando=[self.chequear, quit]
    for i in range(len(lista2)):
        self.listaBoton.append(cpt.crear_B(marcoDos, lista2[i], "10", self.comando[i]))
        cpt.ordenar(self.listaBoton[i], 0, i, 5, 2, "", 1)
```

Y escribir un método `Formularios.chequear()` que ya tendría acceso a `self.listaCaja`  y se la podría pasar como parámetro a `vf.chequear`:

```
class Formularios():
    # ... omito el resto

    def chequear(self):
        return vf.chequear(self.listaCaja)
```